# ASP.NET MVC route does not work if matched with folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC Area and defining route like this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Area51",
            "area51/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" },
            new[] { typeof(TestController).Namespace }
        );
    }
```

But when there is folder in the site named "Area51", URL /area51 is not matched and leads to page not found. URL /area51/test/index works normally.
If I rewrite the url pattern to "area52/{controller}/{action}", URL /area52 works perfectly. Can anybody advise what to so I can use the same route URL as the folder, please?

Comment: This is by design. If a path exists on the filesystem, it will be used. Why do you need a folder the same name as your route?

Comment: I believe if you set `context.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` it will work, but this may have unexpected consequences.

Comment: @Chris: I need it because it is big project and the real folder is called BackOffice (and I don't want to rename it due to namespaces, etc.) and I need /backoffice URL for the business, with your comments it seems that they would have to live with ugly /back-office or something like this :( But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Erik: Unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: @FrantisekJandos - it may also require enabling the correct IIS handler as well, which unfortunately I don't have access to the information at hand.

Comment: @FrantisekJandos - maybe I misunderstand, are you trying to use the folder as the actual url?  as in /backoffice or are you trying to do /backoffice/controller?

Comment: Do you have `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true` set in web.config?